# How to set the frame range for rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

*I use Blender 2.8 cycles.* I rendered my animation from frame 1 to 35 than I, stopped the render because I heard that I can render in more sessions if I render each frame as a picture. Now when I click the render button it starts from frame 1 not from 35. What can I do? I can render each frame, but this it means that I must click render at every frame.

Answer (score 5):

In the *Properties* editor > *Output* panel > *Dimensions*, you can choose at what frame you want the render to start:

[image]