# De-noise pre-rendered image starting from frame 0

Tags: rendering, denoise

So, I have some pre-rendered 3840x2160 images from another program called Source Filmmaker, and I want to de-noise them using Blender. SFM exports images starting with frame number 000000, regardless of how many digits the last frame has. In this case I want to de-noise from frame #000000 to frame #015983. I was able to do this using the de-noise node in Blender 2.81, which worked successfully with SFM's noise samples. However, it seems Blender starts at frame 1 by default, so how can I be sure that Blender starts at frame 0 and the frame numbers match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the frame range for rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149366/how-to-set-the-frame-range-for-rendering)

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for how to do it in animation and image sequence properties and ensure it starts from frame 0.

Comment: The *Image* node should have a *Start Frame* property when loading an image sequence.

Comment: I'd rename the image sequence, 2 seconds, done.